# BOT to ask entity in second step

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Building a simple customer service BOT, have designed the LUIS model and it works great when the order no. is provided in the first step itself. for eg. whats the status of my order ABC0898787 ?
where intent is detected correctly and ABC0898787 is identified as the entity.

However, need to adapt the bot to have a conversation as follows:

User: whats the status of my order

Bot: please provide the order no

User: (It is ABC0986767) or (ABC0986767)

Bot should be able to map the number to entity and process the request.

the code for intent method, whats the best way to integrate the second step without setting up the LUIS model to take single words as entity ?

```
   [LuisIntent("OrderStatus")]
        public async Task OrderStatus(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            var returnMsg = "You wanted to check the order status";
            var orderStatus = "Dispatched";
            var deliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

            var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);
            if(entities.Any((entity)=> entity.Type == "Order"))
            {
                var orderEntity = entities.Where((entity) => entity.Type == "Order").FirstOrDefault();
                var resolutionStr = orderEntity.Entity;
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resolutionStr))
                {
                    returnMsg = "Your order " + resolutionStr + " is " + orderStatus + " and expected to arrive " + deliveryDate.Humanize();
                }
            }

            await context.PostAsync(returnMsg);
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace MessageReceived with the name of your method that will take the user's input. Before that, check if entity exists. If exists, then use MessageReceived, otherwise this method.

Pseudocode:

```
if (entity.exists) 
    OutputResult()
    Context.Wait(MessageReceived)
else //entitiy doesn't exist
    SendMessage("Please enter order number")
    Context.Wait(MyMethod)
```

The method called MyMethod begins like this:

```
public async Task MyMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument) 
{
    var response = await argument;
    string text = response.Text;
```

I think Microsoft didn't make it clear enough that MessageReceived is just a name of a method (that you don't see), and it can be replaced with the name of any other method. There can also be multiple `context.Wait`s in a method depending on a condition, as long as the code doesn't reach a context.Wait() twice before the user sends a new message.

Comment: Tried doing that, but if i use IAwaitable<string> argument, context.Wait throws compilation error. If i user IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> it compiles fine. but the final behavior is NOT correct.

Comment: basically, BOT should prompt the user to provide the order no.

Comment: basically, the bot should prompt the user for the reference no (which is mapped to entity in my LUIS model) and it should use this single word input with the utterance before and LUIS should detect the entity for the same. Not sure if that explains it well enoughh

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it still doesn't solve it

Comment: unfortunately, it still does not ... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11374665/Luis-error.JPG

Comment: I did manage to do it in a different way though and it works as well, dont think this is the best way though... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11374665/Luis-Different-Way.JPG

Comment: Instead of string response you should use var response or IMessageActivity response